# How to export the data to Excel using Groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am trying to fetch the value from response and store into a Excel row wise.
Take an example
Response structure as below, I want all id tag value to be store in Excel sheet.. Currently I am able to do that but all id were appearing in a single row () in excel file, I want this in multiple so that I can use it further, below code I am using to store in Excel.
Please help me out how I can store all the id in row wise in Excel.

```
<Employee>
    <Person>
        <Id>QW1122</id>
        <Address>200</address>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <Id>QW1123</id>
        <Address>200</address>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <Id>QW1124</id>
        <Address>200</address>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <Id>QW1125</id>
        <Address>200</address>
    </Person>
    .
    .
    .
    .
</Employee>

def gu = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
import jxl.*
import jxl.write.*
WritableWorkbook workbook1 = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("C:/Report3.xls"))
WritableSheet sheet1 = workbook1.createSheet("Report Worksheet", 0)
holder = gu.getXmlHolder("Test1#Response")
holder.namespaces["ns1"] = "http://www.siebel.com1" 

for (item in items)
{ 
    Label label = new Label(1, 1, "$items")
    sheet1.addCell(label)
    workbook1.write()
    log.info( item )
}
workbook1.close()
```

Here is an [example of what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQj2K.png) in Excel.

[image]

Comment: For every item, you add a label at `1,1` with all the `items` as a string. You also write the workbook out every item rather than at the end. Slow down a little, you seem to be rushing

Comment: Thanks Tim for your comment, i am new to groovycan you help me how to correct this one

Comment: Why not just write the data out as CSV (a plain text file) an then manipulate it as much as you like in Excel?

Comment: Thanks SiKing fir your comment, but exactly again i have to manipulate it into excel, i have scenario were i want to store the id, row wise then i have to use those id in other request, so if it will be in excel so that i can directly use this file as input.

Comment: You can read a CSV as input

Answer (score 0):

The following code will take the text/value of each ID entry (QW1122, QW1123, etc) and write it to an Excel file. All IDs are written to the same column, but each gets a new row.

```
@Grab('net.sourceforge.jexcelapi:jxl:2.6.12')

import jxl.Workbook
import jxl.write.Label

/*
 * Note: I renamed <Id> to <id> and <Address> to <address>
 * to avoid org.xml.sax.SAXParseException
 */
def input = '''
<Employee>
    <Person>
        <id>QW1122</id>
        <address>200</address>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <id>QW1123</id>
        <address>200</address>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <id>QW1124</id>
        <address>200</address>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <id>QW1125</id>
        <address>200</address>
    </Person>

</Employee>
'''

def workbookFilename = 'Report3.xls'
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(input)

new FileOutputStream(new File(workbookFilename)).withStream {stream ->
    def workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(stream)
    def sheet = workbook.createSheet('Report Worksheet', 0)

    xml.Person.id.eachWithIndex {id, row ->        
        sheet.addCell new Label(0, row, id.text())
    }

    workbook.write()
    workbook.close()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest API (maybe primitive) way to export data friendly to Excell is tab delimited text (or clipboard too)

```
cel1 \t cel2 \t cel3 \n
cel21 \t cel22 \t cel23 \n
```

Sometimes find bugs in excell-alike-api (or/usually bad understanding), or heavy weight of libraries is not worth time for one-shot situations.

BTW some (native, windowc, .net) libraries made cell-by-cell atomic "discussions" with running in background excell engine via OLE, DEE and other way, EXTREMELY slow.

EDIT: in many API, original windows too, if cell has sense of 'String' but content seems be numeric/date etc like `00001` of invoice number `123/08/15` engine is stupid, precede with single `'` i.e. `'00001`